# Maven: How do I reconcile this dependency conflict?

Tags: maven, dependencies, xerces, http-unit

I have this Maven dependency ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javanettasks</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I need this for some tests that I'm running.  This library relies on xercesImpl v 2.4.  Problem is, When we run this through our Bamboo integration server, we get a ClassCastException because our server uses a higher version of xerces.  Does anyone know how I can reconcile this?  In other words, is there a way I can make my xercesImpl take precedence in the classloader during the test phase?

```
29-Nov-2011 12:55:12    Running com.myco.clearing.product.client.xmltohtml.XmlToHtmlServiceTest
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16    Loading inherited module 'com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlusJUnit'
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16       [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.createNewSaxParser(ReflectiveParser.java:65)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.access$000(ReflectiveParser.java:46)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:343)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:296)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$2.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:217)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:324)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.createSyntheticModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:107)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.CompileStrategy.maybeCompileModuleImpl2(CompileStrategy.java:165)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.CompileStrategy.maybeCompileModuleImpl(CompileStrategy.java:112)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.SimpleCompileStrategy.maybeCompileModule(SimpleCompileStrategy.java:36)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1340)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1309)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:653)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:441)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:16            at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:296)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
29-Nov-2011 12:55:17            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: I'm confused: shouldn't your server bundles specify their version of xerces, while the pom in your httpunit specifies whatever it needs? Is it an option to check into their POMs and see that all versions are properly specified? Maybe you could even deploy your own version of httpunit with a different dependency version if it comes to that.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the same `version` of Xerces as a `dependency` in both your client and server projects.  This will take precedence over the transitive dependency on Xerces that `httpunit` has.

However, if `httpunit` is incompatible with the Xerces version that you have declared, then you are in trouble.